# The anti-symmetric property of the collection of all compact convex sets of a Banach space

Tags: gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

**Edit:** According  to  comment of  " Fedor Petrov", I revise  my  question

Are  there  two      compact  convex subsets $X,Y$ of a Banach  space with the following property?

> They  are  not  homeomorphic  spaces  but $X$ can  be  embedded in $Y$ and $Y $ can be embedded in $X$?

Comment: You mean infinite-dinensional Euclidean space? In finite dimension convex compact sets are topologically balls.

Comment: @FedorPetrov  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  comment. I was  not aware of  this  so I revise  my  question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the question is answered in the book Bessaga-Pelczynski, "Selected topics in infinite-dimensional topology", Warsaw, 1975. Combine Theorem 3.1 and Proposition 3.1 in that book (on page 100). The answer is: all such infinite-dimensional sets are homeomorphic to the Hilbert cube. (As for finite-dimensional sets, the question was answered in the classical dimension theory.)

Comment: The article Some Topological Properties of Convex Sets by Victor Klee touches on the same topic (online here: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-078-01/S0002-9947-1955-0069388-5/S0002-9947-1955-0069388-5.pdf). The theorem is also known as the Keller-Klee theorem.

Comment: @Mikhail  Thank you very much  for the answer.